# Present Subjunctive Passive

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, syntax, translation-explanation, conjunctive

North & Hillard Ex. 213; Q5: the following is to be translated into Latin: "I am willing to send anyone at all to find out what is going on."

The answer: "volo quemvis (quemlibet) mittere cognitum quid agatur."

A few points: firstly, two-words-joined-into one, "quem vis" whom-you-want & "quem libet" whom-it-is-pleasing; but doesn't "libet" require dative + infinitive construction giving "cuilibet mittere"?

Secondly, what does "cognitum" mean here; it cannot be "having-been-learned" when the intention is in the future? Is it an acquaintance--the person being sent; if so, how is the concept of "finding out" to be expressed?

Thirdly, present subjunctive passive "agatur", after "quid", giving (literally) "what-may-be-done" referring to the future; but the Q asks for present tense--"what is going on".

Answer (score 6):

1. A couple of indefinite pronouns and adjectives consist of a verbal element + *quis*/*quid* or *qui*/*quae*/*quod*: *quivis*, *quilibet*, and *nescio quis*. These are tricky because the verbal element doesn't affect the form of *quis* or *qui*. Instead, that form is determined by the function of the overall pronoun/adjective in the clause.

   If the pronoun is the direct object, the accusative case is needed, as always, and the form would be *quemvis*, *quemlibet*, or *nescio quem*. To show possession by the pronoun, the form would be *cuiusvis*, *cuiuslibet*, or *nescio cuius*. To show that the pronoun is the indirect object, the form would be *cuivis*, *cuilibet*, or *nescio cui*. And so on. The verbal element doesn't really function as a verb in these words/phrases, though it does color the meaning of the overall pronoun.
2. *Cognitum* is a supine to show purpose, because when you send someone to do something, some degree of motion on that person's part is involved. You could just as well use a different construction here, such as *ad cognoscendum*/*cognoscendi causa* (gerund), *ut cognoscat* (purpose clause), or *qui cognoscat* (relative clause of purpose).
3. The present subjunctive in a subordinate clause (here, an indirect question) may refer to action that's later than the action of the main verb, as you say; but it can also refer to contemporaneous action. In your sentence, the subject is sending someone to find out what's *currently* going on.

Also, as a general rule, subjunctives in Latin indirect questions should be translated without 'may,' 'would,' etc., because they're reflecting questions about actual facts. Obviously, there are exceptions; but this is easily one of the most common corrections that I make with my students.

Therefore, *cognitum quid agatur* means 'to learn what is being done/carried out/performed/etc.' or, more colloquially, 'to learn what is going on.'

Answer (score 5):

On *quemlibet*: it's not the "whoever" that is being pleased, so the *quis/quem* isn't what goes into the dative. I suppose there's an understood *mihi*, or *tibi*; but I suspect that really, *libet* has become lexicalised as a suffix, separated from its verbal root.

On *cognitum*: I think it is a supine, not a participle. I don't remember seeing *mittere cognitum* before - I'm only familiar with this use with *ad*: "ad cognitum" - but I think that's what it must be.

On *agatur*: there isn't a future subjunctive anyway, but why do you think this is has future meaning? The meaning is *what may be happening (being done)*.