# Interpretation of a causal clause in the subjunctive, A&G 5.40

Tags: grammar-identification, interpretation

How should the following sentence from [Allen and Greenough 5.40](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/causal-clauses) be parsed?

*Rediit quodsē oblītum nesciō quid dīceret.* ("He returned because he said that he forgot something.") --Cicero, *De Oficiis* 1.40

Literally, the middle clause seems to say "I do not know myself having forgotten", which I suppose is an idiom for forgetting? To say you "do not know yourself". But then how does the *quid* relate it to *diceret*? Is that the accusative singular pronoun refering to the clause as a whole, ie, "what he said". If so, then how do we infer "something". If I read it naively, nowhere do I see that he says he forgot "something", it just seems to say that he forgot without describing what he forgot (unless it is the *quid* that he forgot, in case shouldn't it be *quidam*--I forgot a certain thing?).

Answer (score 4):

*Nescio quid* is an idiomatic phrase more or less equivalent to *aliquid*. The verb (*nescio*) has lost its syntactical function as a verb. Any good dictionary should provide examples under *nescio*.

This in mind, the sentence is quite easy to interpret: He returned because (*rediit quod*) he said (*diceret*) that he had forgot something (*se oblitum nescio quid*) – the last part being an ordinary accusativus cum infinitivo.

For the subjunctive *diceret* following *quod*, see Allen and Greenough [§ 540](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/causal-clauses):

> The Causal particles ***quod*** and ***quia*** take the indicative, when the reason is given on the authority of the *writer* or *speaker*; the subjunctive, when the reason is given on the authority of *another*.

Comment: That paragraph from A&G does of course *not* explain the subjunctive of *diceret*.

Comment: I see, so the interpretation is "he said himself (to have forgotten) (I-know-not-what)"?

Comment: [Also relevant for nescio quid](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7725/present-subjunctive-passive/8726#8726)

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel You are right! Thanks for pointing it out. But then what does explain it? Perhaps there is something in the larger context (the sentences before).